# JQuery Slider Image

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I have a simple image viewer made with jQuery 1.8, currently working.

When I change the jQuery version to 3.6.0, it stops working. That is, the page loads correctly, but no animation happens. I also don't have bugs in the developer console, so I don't know what happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#slider{
    width: 535px;
    height: 753px;
}
#slider img{
    display: none;
}
#slider img:nth-child(1){
    display: block;
}
.Pad {
            padding-top: 0px; 
            padding-left: 0px; 
            padding-right: 0px; 
            padding-bottom: 0px; 
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
body { 
    background-color:#ffedb0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
$(document).on("ready", main);

function main(){
    var control = setInterval(cambiarSlider, 15000); 
}
function cambiarSlider(){
    i++;
    if(i == $("#slider img").size()){
        i = 0;
    }
    $("#slider img").hide();
    $("#slider img").eq(i).fadeIn("medium");
}
</script>
<body>
<div class="Pad" id="slider">
<img src="01.png" width="535" height="753" />
<img src="02.png" width="535" height="753" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to modify to work with the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: According to https://api.jquery.com/size/, the `.size()` method was deprecated in jQuery v3.0. Use `.length` instead.

Comment: @MarkHillard I've tried to replace that, but it's still not running.